# List of favourite questions to revisit it later in Stack Exchange App

Tags: support, android-app, bookmarks

I was able to mark questions as favourite in Stack Exchange app for android, but now could not find how to get list of it to revisit them.

Comment: The android app is very.... limited. There is no easy way to see list of favorites because, well, it was too hard to implement. Instead you need to use the search mechanism by searching for `infavorites:mine`. Hacky, twisted, but it should work.